# Enable PHP logging in Azure App Service (WebApp)

Tags: php, azure, logging

This has been asked a handful of times, but in 2020 the accepted solution doesn't appear to work. I have uploaded my PHP files to */site/wwwroot* and inside the same *wwwroot* created a *php.ini* file with only one line entry:

```
display_errors=On
```

I also created an App Setting for my WebApp, as below - Key name PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR and value as shown below:

[image]

The website has been restarted. Still no PHP errors displaying. I get a blank page.

Comment: Any update? Does my answer answer your question?

Answer (score 4):

I think it's necessary for you to enable error logging here:

[image]

Then you can go to kudu, a new folder should be found in kudu, this folder holds the error message.